# Bootable USB not working when installing Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu

I have `Ubuntu 16.04` installed in my laptop. But for some reason I have to switch back to `Windows 10`. I am using a bootable USB 3.0. But every time I select the USB from boot option, it starts `Ubuntu` instead of installing `Windows`. I can not figure out the problem.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Have you tried in the bios to change this and make the usb a priority in the bios options? I think it's something like that

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too. But no luck.

Comment: Have you changed the boot order in the bios? Does the bios detect the USB?

Comment: Yes. Already did that.

Comment: Does the bios detect the USB?

Comment: No. Automatically the bios doesn't detect the USB.

Comment: For clarification purposes are you trying to completely remove Ubuntu and go back to windows 10

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer and OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].